# Передача данных между классами/потоками виджета Android

Tags: android, виджет, android-widgets, storage, android-bundle

Есть объект содержимого, его нужно передавать между классами и потоками. Вот как я вижу его путь в программе. Сначала вызывается конфигурационное активити там пользователь указывает 1 параметр и нажимает на кнопку. По нажатию кнопки я кладу этот параметр в объект содержимого. Далее мне надо по этим данным скачать HTML док. и пропарсить его. Это можно сделать ТОЛЬКО создав новый поток. Поток берет тот параметр из содержимого, генерирует ссылку по этому параметру, скачивает документ и парсит его, результат кладет опять же в содержимое.  Пока данные скачиваются из интернета, я создаю виджет с прогресс баром, когда тот поток скачал и запарсил все, он обновляет виджет с контентом.

Если не сериализовать, а просто хранить в каком-то поле, то программа не работает, т.к. GC нагло удаляет этот объект(если оперативки на телефоне мало). Могу ли я изменить layout виджета в этом потоке? Да могу, но это не по его части + все равно мне нужен контент в методе onRecieve.

Вот и кодик подъехал)

```
public class Content implements Serializable {
public long creationDate; //Дата создания виджета
public String group; // строка для скачивания и парсинга
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> info = null; //содержимое виджета
public Content() {
    super();
}

public Content(String group, long creationDate) {
    this.group = group;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getInfo(){
    return info;
}

public void setInfo(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array) {
    info = array;
}
}
```

Нажатие:

```
View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Context context = LessonWidgetConfigureActivity.this;
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final String group = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Content content = new Content(group, new Date().getTime());
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable(Integer.toString(mAppWidgetId), content);
        RequestThread thread = new RequestThread(context, mAppWidgetId, group);
        thread.start();
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        LessonWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

        // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
    }
};
```

В самом классе виджета ничего интересного нет, просто заполнение виджета контентом через RemoteViews, но чтобы заполнить нужно получить данные!!
Как я понял это как-то через Bundle и putSeriazible, но как? Я кладу через интент, но в классе виджета или потока я не могу получить интент т.к. они не унаследуются от активити. Как грамотно выйти из данной ситуации?
Извиняйте за количество текста).